# Memory release while reassign char * to null

Tags: visual-c++

I'm a little bit confused regarding string memory usage in c++.

Is it good reassign *PChar to  NULL second time? Will assigned first time to *PChar string memory be released?

```
char * fnc(int g)
{
...
}

char *PChar = NULL;
PChar=fnc(1);
if (PChar) { sprintf(s,"%s",PChar); } ;

*PChar = NULL;
PChar=fnc(2);
if (PChar) { sprintf(s,"%s",PChar); } ;
```

Comment: Is memory being dynamically allocated inside `fnc` with `new` or `malloc`?

Comment: High odds that you shot your foot with this function by returning a pointer to a local variable.  Never write code like this, nobody can ever tell whether or not the returned pointer needs to be released.  Nor can we.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first. The following statement is not what you intend:

```
*PChar = NULL;
PChar=fnc(2);
```

You are NOT assigning null to the pointer, but putting value zero (0) to the first character of the said buffer. You might be willing to do:

```
   PChar = NULL;
   PChar=fnc(2);
```

As a good programming practice, yes you should assign a pointer to null after it is used (AND possibility memory-deallocated). But assigning a pointer to null will not free the memory - the pointer will not point to allocated memory, but to non-existent memory location. You need to call `delete` if it was allocated using `new`, or need to call `free` if allocated by `malloc`.

As for the given statement, the compiler would anyway remove the following statement, as the process of optimization:

```
 // PChar = NULL;
 PChar=fnc(2);
```

You need to be very careful while using pointers, and assignment to it with a statically allocated data or dynamically allocated buffer!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest declaring a buffer of the PChar type and pass pointer to this buffer in a function call.
Good programming practice cals for passing also the allowed length of the buffer that should be checked in th function.

```
#define MAX_PCHAR_LEN 1024 // or constant const DWORD . . .

PChar PCharbuf[MAX_PCHAR_LEN] = {0}; // initialize array with 0s

//make a call
fnc (&PCharbuf, MAX_PCHAR_LEN, 2); // whatever 2 means
```

This way you do not have to worry about who allocates and who released memory, since release is automatic after PCharbuf goes out of scope.